# Admin toolbar in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

Is it possible to make admin toolbar partially visible to newly created users in Drupal 8? For example, the user would be able to observe the Reports, but not be able to add new modules, so the 'Extend' entry is not visible to him?

Answer (score 0):

You, as an admin, would have to set the user permissions to limit access.

You limit access to module configuration under "System" at this path: /admin/people/permissions